# Python List and Range integration

Tags: python, list, range

Ok, a simple one!
I have a list as follows:

```
SeqF = []
SeqF = range(0, 8)
SeqF[0] = [1,0,0,0]
SeqF[1] = [1,1,0,0]
SeqF[2] = [0,1,0,0]
SeqF[3] = [0,1,1,0]
SeqF[4] = [0,0,1,0]
SeqF[5] = [0,0,1,1]
SeqF[6] = [0,0,0,1]
SeqF[7] = [1,0,0,1]
```

Please can someone explain to me in English what this is?  I get that it is a list, there is a range (0-8), but I can't get my head around it and google is getting fed up with me.

Would a more 'pythonic' way be:

```
SeqF = [[1,0,0,0],
        [1,1,0,0],
        [0,1,0,0],
        [0,1,1,0],
        [0,0,1,0],
        [0,0,1,1],
        [0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,1]]
```

Comment: You're just overwriting `SeqF` a bunch of times, so yes your bottom code is more concise

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: N.B. this doesn't work in Python3, where `range` gives you a range object, not a list, so your `SeqF[0]` would throw a `TypeError` when you try to assign to it

Comment: I know there was limited code here but the full programme is quite lengthy.  It is the cycle of steps for a stepper motor... in a computerised BBQ!!  I now need to work out how to step though it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the python3 [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range):

> Rather than being a function, `range` is actually an immutable sequence type

Setting items in a range like you showed is not Pythonic, and I'm surprised it actually works.  (EDIT: it would only work in python2, where `range` returned a `list`)

The second option you showed is called a `list` literal, and is definitely the more Pythonic approach.

Comment: In Py2, `range` returned a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> SeqF = []
>>> SeqF = range(0, 8)
>>> SeqF[0] = [1,0,0,0]
>>> SeqF[1] = [1,1,0,0]
>>> SeqF[2] = [0,1,0,0]
>>> SeqF[3] = [0,1,1,0]
>>> SeqF[4] = [0,0,1,0]
>>> SeqF[5] = [0,0,1,1]
>>> SeqF[6] = [0,0,0,1]
>>> SeqF[7] = [1,0,0,1]
>>> SeqF
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

You've produced the same thing in the bottom code in one line to that of 10 in the top line. So yes, this is definitely a more efficient and 'pythonic' way.